# XMLPullParserException when trying to call wcf web service

Tags: android, wcf, ksoap2, xmlpullparser

I'm having problems connecting to my web service. I've followed a couple of tutorials, especially http://drclawx.wordpress.com/2011/06/24/77/ and created a simple Wcf Hello World web service. I've downloaded the ksoap2 jar recommended on the site, but I had a couple of problems. I've downloaded a couple of later versions but the one that I can get to work is version 2.5.8. When I go to call my own web service I'm getting an XMLPullParserException. My web service will be used to check login credentials, it has a method called 'UploadLogin' which takes a username and password. The following is my code

```
private class webService extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    final String METHOD_NAME = "UploadLogin";
    final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";     
    final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:52762/UploadService.svc";
    final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IUploadService/UploadLogin";

    // For the web service method: public String getLocations(String inputLocation))
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... entry) {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("username", "a");
        request.addProperty("password", "a");
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            Object response = (Object) envelope.getResponse();
            System.out.println("Login - " + response.toString());
        } 
        catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();   
        }

        return null;
    } 
}
```

The error that I'm getting is the following. Can someone please help or suggest how I might go about fixing this issue.

```
12-04 18:50:44.317: W/System.err(1704): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT 
12-04 18:50:44.317: W/System.err(1704): --uuid:e537e5f2...@3:13 in java.io.InputStreamReader@41325c88) 
12-04 18:50:44.326: W/System.err(1704):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:426)
12-04 18:50:44.336: W/System.err(1704):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:310)
12-04 18:50:44.336: W/System.err(1704):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextTag(KXmlParser.java:2029)
12-04 18:50:44.346: W/System.err(1704):     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:126)
12-04 18:50:44.356: W/System.err(1704):     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:96)
12-04 18:50:44.356: W/System.err(1704):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:189)
12-04 18:50:44.366: W/System.err(1704):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95)
12-04 18:50:44.376: W/System.err(1704):     at prometric.myitemwriter.ViewItemBankActivity$ws_MIR.doInBackground(ViewItemBankActivity.java:538)
12-04 18:50:44.376: W/System.err(1704):     at prometric.myitemwriter.ViewItemBankActivity$ws_MIR.doInBackground(ViewItemBankActivity.java:1)
12-04 18:50:44.396: W/System.err(1704):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-04 18:50:44.426: W/System.err(1704):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-04 18:50:44.436: W/System.err(1704):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-04 18:50:44.516: W/System.err(1704):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-04 18:50:44.516: W/System.err(1704):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
12-04 18:50:44.526: W/System.err(1704):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
12-04 18:50:44.536: W/System.err(1704):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that's interested, the reason I was getting this error was because the messageEncoding was using MTOM, so I changed this to Text and it work - messageEncoding="Text"

Comment: Where did you set message encoding ? i need your help

Comment: how do you set message encoding? please post the solution

Comment: Hi all, sorry for the lateness of the reply. The Message Encoding is set within the bindings tab and then within the wsHttpBinding tab within that. You can then set the property messageEncoding="Text" from here. Hope this helps

Comment: Hey Graham , i also getting this same issue , can you please check my question, there i mentioned my code with wsdl... :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31200944/org-xmlpull-v1-xmlpullparserexception-unexpected-token-positiontext-resultc

Answer (score 2):

```
Instead of using kSOAP library, you can do it with built-in apache classes like HttpClient, HttpGet, HttpPost, etc.

For example: You want to send below JSON object:

{
   "email":"test@test.com",
   "password":"test"
}
then you can set your request object by using setEntity():

final String body = String.format("{\"email\":\"%s\",\"password\":\"%s\"}", s1, s2);

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(webServiceUrl);
postMethod.setEntity(new StringEntity(body, "utf-8"));
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the error occurred because of the lack of the required method parameter:

```
    request.addProperty("cpf", "111111111");
```